# Emberjs passing params to components that come from a service

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to put together a dynamic navbar, in doing so I want all the buttons to be adjustable per route.

Each button is a very simple component for example:

```
<!--features/components/button-edit/template.hbs-->
{{#link-to "accounts.edit" classNames="button is-normal is-outlined is-dark"}}
    Edit
{{/link-to}}
```

and

```
//features/components/button-edit/component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  classNames: ['nav-item'],
});
```

I have a service

```
// features/navigation/service.js
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  visibleOptions: []
});
```

and inside each route I pass into the service which buttons I want to display on that route

```
//features/accounts/view/route.js:4
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  navigationService: Ember.inject.service('navigation'),

  activate() {
    this.get('navigationService').set('visibleOptions', ['button-new', 'button-edit']);
  },

});
```

So I can loop over them in the frontend

```
      {{#each navigationService.visibleOptions as |option|}}
        {{component option}}
      {{/each}}
```

This works well and does what I want, the problem is I can't figure out how I can pass things like models into the button component. For example the edit button needs the model.id for the link...

So how can I go about getting things into each component, should I try and read them off the controller once inside the component, or should they be passed in somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't inject `controller` in `component`. so you have to pass it.
In `component` helper will  accept arguments so you can pass it

```
      {{#each navigationService.visibleOptions as |option|}}
        {{component option model.id }}
      {{/each}}
```

Comment: But with that template block sitting in its own component, and the component being registered on the application template, how do I get the model into that component?

Comment: While including component in  application template, you  need to pass required arguments so that you can send that to `component`.

Comment: I know, but how do I get the model from say the edit route into the application route in the first place? I've tried `this.modelFor(this.routeName)` on the application route but always returns `undefined`

Comment: As you know, from edit route you can get model used in application route but reverse is not possible.

Comment: So one way i can think of sharing state using service. may be we can wait until some one will come enlighten us.